# change of icons and launch screen in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, icons

hopeing for some help on this one

Hi set my icons up in xcode for using the neat drag and drop feature.  A week later i made amendments to my icons.  Drag and dropped the new amended items in deleting the older versions.  The new versions show up on in the summary drag and drop section and in my project files yet when I build and run it is still showing the older versions even though i have deleted them.

Hope someone can help me out in this one.  Not sure if it makes a difference, but im building the app to the simulator.

Thanks in advance for any tips on this one.

Cheers,
Laff

Answer (score 0):

Open your iPhone simulator and select 'Reset Content and Settings' and try running your application on simulator.

Comment: Yeah I tried that.  Closed the simulator and xcode.  Even empted the trash to wich the older items had been dispposed and for good lucj reset my mac!  But still it is showing the older icon and launch screen.  All seems odd.  Would like to know if anyone else has experienced this even if you dont have the soloution as it is driving me up the wall and would be nice to know that it is not just me that seems to have incountered this bug!?

Comment: Me too have faced that problem once. I just reset the iPhone simulator and worked fine.

Comment: Check for the launch screen and icon in the app bundle. You may have them inside the bundle by mistake. If it is there, delete it.

Comment: Can you talk me through checking the launch screen and icon in the app bundle?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The only way that i could get it to recognise the changes was to put them into a new folder.  And eveytime i need to change the icons i drag them out of the folder build and run and it chages to them to the new ones.  Seems odd, but works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Clean (also delete the build folder on disk) and rebuild the project. Also Delete the app from simulator.  This way you make sure nothing stale got stuck.